# MATE desktop doesn't work correctly

Tags: pi-3b+, ubuntu

So, I decided to install the KDE Plasma desktop and see how it would go. I installed it (all dependencies took up 1.3GB of storage) and tried it out, and didn't like it too much. It takes about ~100MB more than MATE. MATE does a badass job at displaying themes correctly. So, I removed them, but only freed up about 230MB (RIP 800 megs). However, after I switched back to MATE, some things don't work as they should. For example, I've set the theme to a certain color and some parts do not apply. This happened after I installed KDE plasma and Ubuntu desktops.

(Check out the thread https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/mate-desktop-doesnt-work-correctly/23511 to see the images for examples!)

I swear I removed the `KDE-plasma-desktop` and `ubuntu-desktop` already, and in Terminal it says they are not installed, but on the login, I have the option to select the desktops.

It seems I can boot into the desktops, but I already removed them so...?
It bugs me because I want everything to have a certain color, and it fails. I tried  `dconf reset -f /` but that didn't work. I tried to go to Appearance and select a different theme, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 800 MB you have lost, try running `apt autoremove` and `apt clean`: the first one removes packages which were installed as dependencies and are no longer needed, and the second one clears the cached `.deb` files.

Removing unused dependencies could help you with your other problems, but I wouldn't bet on it.